# Why can't I assign a function to a variable using prototype?

Tags: javascript

I keep on trying to assign a function to a variable and I keep getting a message saying foo is not a function. I am not sure why it is saying that. When I invoke the method by itself it works, but when I assign it to a variable it won't work.

Can anyone please help me figure this out? Thank you!!!

Below is my code:

```
function Test(){

    function foo(){
        return "foo";
    }

    this.bar = function () {
        var foo = foo();
        console.log(foo);
    };
}
var test = new  Test();
test.bar();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code will work. As Now we are not trying to assign same function variable to variable.

The problem is because JavaScript is function scoped. It is failing because this.bar function will try to evaluate foo first and foo is name of variable in this function so interpreter will try to execute the foo but foo is variable in this scope it will not consider foo mentioned above. Hence it fails.

Where as foo1 will work because when interpreter hits the term foo1 it will look for current scope and all parent scopes and it will get it.

```
function Test(){

function foo1(){

    return "foo";
}


this.bar = function () {

    var foo = foo1();

    console.log(foo);

};

}


var test = new  Test();
test.bar();
```

Answer (score 5):

The culprit is this line `var foo = foo();`. The statement `var foo` is redeclaring the local foo variable. By the time you try to access it with `foo()` it has become an `undefined` variable.

Rename the variable or the function and everything works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Error is at this line

```
var foo = foo();
```

Your variable `foo` has the same name as the function, that hides the function outside.

Renaming it will resolve the error.

```
var foo1 = foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

There error you're seeing is from this line:

```
var foo = foo();
```

When you use `var` there you are saying that `foo` is being defined for the current level of scope (`this.bar`) - meaning it won't bubble up to `Test`. You can either rename the variable to something else:

```
var result = foo();
console.log(result);
```

or just forgo that variable altogether like this:

```
console.log(foo());
```

totally your choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are learning how to create and work with JavaScript objects, you may want to rewrite your code like so:

```
// This function constructs the object when called with new
function Test(prop) {
    // Some arbitrary property
    if (typeof prop === "undefined") {
        prop = null;
    } 
    this.prop = prop;
}

// The two functions
Test.prototype.foo = function() {
    return "foo";
}

Test.prototype.bar = function() {
    var foo = this.foo();
    console.log(foo);
}

// Create the object and call foo
var test = new Test('p');
test.bar();
```

> All JavaScript objects inherit the properties and methods from their
>   prototype. Objects created using an object literal, or with new
>   Object(), inherit from a prototype called Object.prototype. Objects
>   created with new Date() inherit the Date.prototype. The
>   Object.prototype is on the top of the prototype chain.

From: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am not trying to learn how to use javascript.. I just rewrote an easy to use snipped from a working code I already have. But thanks a lot fro the explanation!